# Firebase / Angularfire Localstorage

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm experimenting with Firebase for the first time and I'd like clarification on how the localstorage part of firebase exactly works.

In my test application I have an "events" database and each document has the following structure:

```
{
    "ref": String,
    "message": {
        type: String,
        content: String
    }
}
```

`ref` contains a reference to an environment ID and I'm using the following code to only display `events` that match `ref` (using Angularfire)

```
$scope.events = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild('ref').equalTo($scope.env.environment._id));
```

**My question is this**: Does Firebase/Angularfire download the entire "events" database and then filter it locally, or does it send a filtered request to the firebase server? If it's not the latter, what happens when I have over a million `events`?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Queries filter on the server. So:

```
ref.orderByChild('ref').equalTo($scope.env.environment._id)
```

This entire instruction is sent to the server and executed there. Only the children matching the condition are synchronized to the client.